# Monitoring Java application with Python

Tags: java, python, jmx

I'm a **python** programmer, and want to **monitor a Java application**,
by communicating with **JMX**.

I've been searching the web and I haven't found a proved solution.
I've looked at *jmx4python* and *JPype* but I haven't maid up my mind about them.
*Py4J* doesn't look useful.

Does anyone have a suggestion of a Framework or a way to do this?

btw - The application is already running and I don't want to invoke it

Comment: I have the same issue like you.  what is your solution at last?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jolikia is an http-jmx that can help you : http://www.jolokia.org

Answer (score 2):

You could use [jython](http://www.jython.org/) to interface with Java's JMX libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to utilize Jython (http://jython.org) for this task. It can call all of the fancy JMX stuff without you having to rewrite the binary protocol stuff that it uses, in the comfort of Python syntax.

Note, however, that Jython isn't 100% compatible with CPython (usually library related stuff), though in practice it's pretty darn good. The current version of Jython seems to support the language defined by CPython 2.7.

Comment: Jython isn't fully compatible and slower than python so i'm trying to avoid suing it.
Moreover my infra is python based and i don't want to mix it up.

I'm currently checking *Jolokia* and trying to use it as a HTTP/JSON Bridge.
Using this bridge i will use REST API and access the JMX.
Which is what jmx4python basically does but it doesn't look so ripped.

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do? It doesn't look like jmx4py is very useful--doesn't support all that much. You might have to hack on it to get it to suit your needs. As for JPype, personally, I'd use Jython over it. Jython is actively developed, and in use by a large number of companies. It's just a matter of how you actually need to access the data, I guess... Sorry I'm not more helpful.