# How to Monitor Health of Kafka Brokers and Consumers (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, health-monitoring

I am working on streaming data using Kafka cluster, my system has multiple brokers and a big consumer group. Now i want to use another **Python** service to monitor health of each broker and consumer. Could anyone suggest me what is the best way for me. Is there anything "like four letter word" methods of zookeeper, or some other way using which i can create something similar to 4lw.

Comment: There are many production-ready monitoring tools available out there. Would these be an option for you or do you need to write your own in Python?

Comment: Why are you specifically wanting to use Python to monitor? Would other monitoring solutions be relevant here?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous, No , Actually i want to build a customised tool of my own which will monitor Kafka and other services i have. Thats why i am looking for python APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka exposes several metrics via [JMX](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html) for broker, produce and consumer. Depending on your monitoring requirement you can choose the appropriate metric.

For accessing them through python you can use Jython or jolokia plugin. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900067/monitoring-java-appliction-with-python) answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Is it the only way possible, i am looking for something more cleaner using python Kafka client, I figured out that Kafka maintains an internal topic from where i can get consumer stats.

Comment: @TajUddin Can you please describe how did you succeed of checking Kafka consumers healthiness in Python?

Comment: @Serjik I managed to get some useful stats (most importantly Lag per partition) using Kafka consumer methods (highwater() and position()). highwater gives offset where producer will produce next and position gives offset from where consumer will read next. difference will give lag. i logged this for all assigned partition and made other service fetch this data periodically from logs. you can follow https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html    for more stats you can also explore metrics() from same documentation.